# Send email when someone check-out a page

Tags: sharepoint-designer

There is a way to trigger an workflow to send an email when someone check-out or check-in a doc in SharePoint?

PS: SharePoint Designer

SharePoint 2013

Answer (score 0):

Are you beyond the thought of creating a Remote Event Receiver for your list?  It has the ability to handle an item checking out / in.  Check out the FAQ at
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn456315(v=office.15).aspx
and see if this is a possible solution for you.